# Style.css is not loaded in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, styles

I'm trying out a plugin test where I've created a simple plugin that will wrap text in a `<span>` element with a class, when I in the editor wrap the text in a shortcode.

It works. But the css styling in the `style.css` file for that plugin isn't applied.

The plugin script is this:

```
class shs_wrap {
    
    /*Create shortcode [wrap]*/
    function shs_wrap() {
        add_shortcode( 'wrap', array( &$this, 'shortcode' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'style' ) );
    }
        
    /*Run the shortcode*/
    function shortcode( $atts , $content = null) {
        
        /*If the "class" is forgotten in the shortcode, abort*/
        if( empty(preg_quote($atts['class'])) || empty($content))
            return;
        
        /*Prepare output*/
        $output = "<span class='".$atts['class']."'>" . $content . "</span>";
        
        return $output;

    }
    
    /*Add styling from the css-file*/
    function style() {
        wp_register_style( 'style', plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ));
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
    }

}

new shs_wrap();
```

When writing

> Here is some text `[wrap class="test"]`here is some wrapped text`[/wrap]` here is some more text

I simply want the output to be:

> Here is some text `<span class="test">`here is some wrapped text`</span>` here is some more text

My script above works and I can see in the source code that the `<span>` element is correctly added with its class - here is a screenclip from the inspection tool:

[image]

The css styling from the `style.css` file is not loaded, though. The output on the screen is not styled and the style file is never added. The style file is located at the same location as the php-file (called `shs-wrap.php`):

[image]

and it contains only this tiny css snippet:

[image]

What is the issue here? Is there an error in my style enqueue function? Do I call it wrongly?

Comment: Confirming... so there are no `<link />` tag in the source html referencing your `style.css`?

Comment: @mikerojas Correct, there is no `<link>` element to this `style.css` file in the source code. It seems to not be loaded at all.

Comment: do you have any other themes or plugins enabled with that are loading their own styles?  Im wondering if there is a naming clash using `style` as the name (too generic).  Let. me know if using a more unique name `my-plugin-test-style`  does anything?

Answer (score 1):

May just be me but I think you should use `__construct` like below in addition to a more unique style handle:

```
class shs_wrap {
    
  /*Create shortcode [wrap]*/
  function __construct() {
    add_shortcode( 'wrap', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'style' ) );
  }
        
  /*Run the shortcode*/
  function shortcode( $atts , $content = null) {
      
    /*If the "class" is forgotten in the shortcode, abort*/
    if( empty(preg_quote($atts['class'])) || empty($content)) {
      return;
    }
    
    /*Prepare output*/
    $output = "<span class='".$atts['class']."'>" . $content . "</span>";
    
    return $output;

  }
  
  /*Add styling from the css-file*/
  function style() {
    wp_register_style( 'my-plugin-test-style', plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-test-style' );
  }

}

new shs_wrap();
```